# compare length of command line arguments in c

Tags: c, command, compare

qz6_2.c can be compiled to a.exe, qz6_2.exe, or any name you prefer. When it is executed at command line, it prints a message "The longest command line argument(s): ............." to tell which argument(s) is the longest (i.e., containing the most characters), including the command itself (see 1st and 3rd execution in the screenshot below.). If more than one argument satisfies the condition, they should be all listed (see 2nd execution in the screenshot below.)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a4yHx.png)

this is what i have now, how do i modify to show multiple arguments if they have same length
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ulUji.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow! Please, don't post code as images, insert it in the body of the post, put three backticks before it and three backticks after it to format it as a code.

Answer (score 0):

You can have 2 for-loops. In the first for-loop you find the maximum length like you do now, in the second loop you print all command line arguments with this length.